# how to get uid from its child data (firebase)?

Tags: java, android, firebase

i have firebase like this:

Projcect-name

```
-Users
   -5Z7mkzYGrdMVxkDmPNpUvt8f9Td2
       email:-------------
       name:-------
       phone:79xx9978xx**
```

i have only an edittext of phone.
i need uid of that phone.
how to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this piece of code to go though the Firebase database looking for the `phoneNumber`(the one you have) and comparing it to all the phone numbers in `phone` node in your database.

And if you succeed in finding one, getting the `key()` of that child node.

```java
 mFirebaseRef = new Firebase("https://yours.firebaseio.com");
    mFirebaseRef.orderByChild("phone").equalTo(phoneNumber).addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            for (DataSnapshot child: dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                Log.i("MainActivity", child.getKey());
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(FirebaseError firebaseError) {
            Log.e("MainActivity", "onCancelled", firebaseError.toException());
        }
    });
```

Comment: Great, Glad I could help :) I'd appreciate if you could upvote and mark the answer as correct. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

You can get the `uid` like this following:

```
String currentuser = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid();
```